# percentage of filled array in java

Tags: java

In this class I need if the array tabletet is filled 75% or not
It has to be with a method (readyPorosia) it is filled 
Any better sugestions please

```
public class Porosia
{

    private String shifraPorosia;
    private int pozita;
    private Tableti [] tabletet;
/* */
    public Porosia(String sh, int nr)
    {

        tabletet = new Tableti[nr];
        shifraPorosia = sh;
    }

    public void addTablet(Tableti t)
    {
        if(t == null){
            System.out.println("Tablet can't be added");
        }else if(full()){
            System.out.println("Tablet can't be added.It's full");
        }else{
            tabletet[pozita++] = t;
            System.out.println("Tablet added");
        }
    }

    public boolean full()
    {
        if(pozita >= tabletet.length){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean readyPorosia(Tableti [] t)
    {
     ///in here to find the percentage of how much is filled the array
        if(percentage >= 75){
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Porosia por = new Porosia("12122/2015",50);

        por.addTablet(new Tableti("Samsung",7));
        por.addTablet(new Tableti("Apple",10));
        por.addTablet(new Tableti("Dell",20));

        Tableti t4 = new Tableti("Lenovo",2);
        por.addTablet(t4);


        por.readyPorosia(por);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use an ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the filled percentage, it's `100*pozita/tabletet.length`. You can compare that number to 75.

```
public boolean readyPorosia(Tableti [] t)
{
    int percentage = 100*pozita/tabletet.length;
    if(percentage >= 75){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more precise to just do: `double percentage = pozita/tabletet.length;  if (percentage >= 0.75){...}` It would be a little more precise would it not?

Comment: @CalebB first of all, you'll have to cast pozita to double, to avoid int division, which would return either 0 or 1. Beside that point, I'm not sure if it would make much difference in terms of precision, since you can express the percentage you test against as an int (75) and the condition is >=, so it doesn't matter if percentage was exactly 75 or truncated down to 75 due to the usage of int.

Comment: that's a good point, I didn't think of that. Thanks for clarifying that.